# What's the percentage of zoom needed to see protozoa in an optical microscope?

Tags: microscopy

I was searching for a microscope and I saw some with prices of over 10.000$. However I need to buy one that can actually show me the cells of a culture I am growing at home, and I really need to know how much "zoom" I need to see them.

Comment: Hi Caju. Welcome to Bio.SE! What attempts to answer this question have you already taken? We ask that all question posters here attempt to search for an answer to their own question and explicitly indicate what research they've already done, what they learned, and what is still confusing or unknown to them. Our goal is not to simply be an answer site, but rather a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help along the way :). Please take a moment to edit your post with this additional detail, and it will likely be received more positively by our community. Thanks!

Comment: specifically, a quick Google search can show you [approximate organism sizes](http://sitn.hms.harvard.edu/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/joe3.png), approximate [protozoan sizes](https://www.tulane.edu/~wiser/protozoology/notes/protist.gif), and [how magnification and size relate](https://www.bbc.com/bitesize/guides/z3vypbk/revision/3). Please perform your own google searches and report back what you find and what you are still confused about. Demonstrating additional effort will certainly result in your question receiving a more positive response from most of our community. Thanks, Caju!

Comment: Not an answer since I'm a long, long way from being an expert, but 10,000 dollars is far too much to pay for a hobbyist-level microscope.  300 dollars is a reasonable ballpark, and IMHO magnifications above 400X or so aren't much use.  I found this site to be helpful: https://www.microscope.com/how-to-buy/

Answer (score 1):

You can see a few like paramecium with good bare eyes. A 10 magnification loup will reveal more. For general amateur use a stand held binocular ( not distance type binoculars) is very versatile, and common, traditionally 7 X to 40 x magnification. Any more magnification will require special lights ,sample preparation , etc.

Comment: When I was much younger ( and eyes were sharper) .I watched paramecium and rotifers in my aquarium. I used various microscopes all my adult life but never published , as most metallurgists could say the same.

Comment: You don't really need special lights (other that the normal below-stage light), or sample prep beyond putting a drop of liquid on a slide and a cover glass over it, to see a good many microorganisms.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, seemingly, the microscope I'm willing to buy is more than enough for what I wanna do!